# 2 bezier path to skspritenode

Tags: swift, xcode8, uibezierpath, skspritenode

I would like to create SKSpriteNode from 2 independent bezier paths.

It is similar like road borders. Those paths don't cross but I would like to get 1 SpriteNode as a border of player movement.

The reason is that I want to get equal distance between them. I think that it will be easier for me if I make 1 SkSpriteNode from 2 paths.

I need SKSpriteNode to get contact when player touches that "border"

How to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Add an `SKSpriteNode`:**

```
let container = SKSpriteNode.init(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(800, 400))
    container.position=CGPointMake(300, 300)
    self.addChild(container)
```

**Create an array of `CGPoint`'s. I used just a triangle you can use whatever you want:**

```
let firstPathArray:[CGPoint]=[CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0),CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100)]
```

**Add path to container:**

```
addbezierPathToContainer(container,pathArray: firstPathArray)
```

**Add path:**

```
func addbezierPathToContainer(container:SKSpriteNode,pathArray:[CGPoint]) -> Void {
    let newpath = UIBezierPath()
    var startpoint:Bool=false;
    for path in pathArray {
        if(!startpoint)
        {
            newpath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: path.x, y: path.y))
            startpoint=true;
        }
        else
        {
            newpath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: path.x, y: path.y))
            newpath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: path.x, y: path.y))
        }


    }
    //close path
    newpath.closePath()
    UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
    newpath.stroke()
    let pathNode = SKShapeNode(path: newpath.CGPath)
    container.addChild(pathNode);
}
```